# VBA cell selection "application.union" with cells()

Tags: vba, charts, selection

I'm having trouble selecting parts of two different lines in a sub.
My sub must create a chart with these lines a `DataSource`, and the number of the second line is an argument of the procedure. `CompteLigneDebut` and `CompteColonnefin` are functions that I defined earlier, they return an integer.
Here's the part that causes the issue, the specific line that causes an error is `set x...`   :

```
Sub test(ligne As Integer)
    Dim graphe As Chart
    Dim x As Range
    Set graphe = Charts.Add
    graphe.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    Set x = Application.Union(Range(Cells(ligne, 2), Cells(ligne, CompteColonneFin)), Range(Cells(CompteLigneDebut, 2), Cells(CompteLigneDebut, CompteColonneFin - 1)))
    graphe.SetSourceData (x)
```

Thank you for your help/advice

Comment: Do you get an exception? Doesn't the chart show the data you expect? What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the "set x..." line, the variable x can't receive what's in the "Application.union(...)" I think I didn't write it correctly.

Comment: without the values of the variables it is quite hard to see. Again: Do you get an error message? Did you try to do that with simple ranges? This small test does work fine: 

    Sub test()
    Dim objRange As Range
    
    Set objRange = Application.Union(Range("A1"), Range("A2"))
    objRange.Value = "Test"
End Sub
Please add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Union` looks ok and the code below works fine for me. I think one of your functions is the problem.

```
Sub RunTheTest()

    test 3

End Sub
Sub test(ligne As Integer)
    Dim x As Range

    Set x = Application.Union(Range(Cells(ligne, 2), Cells(ligne, CompteColonneFin)), Range(Cells(CompteLigneDebut, 2), Cells(CompteLigneDebut, CompteColonneFin - 1)))

End Sub

Private Function CompteColonneFin() As Integer
    CompteColonneFin = 2
End Function

Private Function CompteLigneDebut() As Integer
    CompteLigneDebut = 2
End Function
```

Try splitting the `Application.Union` line into smaller bits. Then check what values the functions return.

```
Sub test(ligne As Integer)
    Dim x As Range
    Dim colonneFin As Integer
    Dim ligneDebut As Integer

    colonneFin = CompteColonneFin()
    ligneDebut = CompteLigneDebut()

    Set x = Range(Cells(ligne, 2), Cells(ligne, colonneFin))
    Set x = Application.Union(x, Range(Cells(ligneDebut, 2), Cells(ligneDebut, colonneFin - 1)))

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i did what you told me, and the error indeed comes from one of my functions, "CompteColonneFin"

Comment: While Not Cells(i, 1).Value = "Row Labels"                                                             This line has an error, I think it's because the sheet isn't precised

Comment: Solved this problem, but now the "set x" line makes an error ("424 object required"). Isn't the application.union the same type as x ? (Range)

Comment: Your comment that starts `While Not Cells(i, 1).Value = "Row Labels" ` means nothing to me. This is not in your original problem code. As for your second comment, did you change your code so it matches mine? Check your functions again. You should prob start a new post.

Comment: I'm trying to, but I can't find how haha